# ChatGPT in Python API: No dialogue considered, isolated Q&A without history

Tags: python-3.x, chatgpt-api

I am using this code to connect to ChatGPT in Python. What I get is a terminal, similar to the web version. However, the problem is that ChatGPT doesn't seem to learn from the conversation.
For instance, when I ask 'How high is the Eiffel Tower in Paris?', it answers correctly.
But when I follow up with 'How high was it in 1955?', ChatGPT doesn't understand the context and doesn't know that we're still talking about the Eiffel Tower. Additionally, I'm having trouble outputting parts of the dialogue."

```
import openai

class ChatGPT:
    def __init__(self, api_key,rolle):
        # Set the OpenAI API key
        openai.api_key=api_key
        # Initialize the dialog list and create the first element with the system role and the passed role
        self.dialog=[{"role":"system","content":rolle}]
    
    def fragen(self, frage):
        # Create a new dictionary with the role "user" and the content of the question
        neue_frage = {"role":"user","content":frage}
        # Add the new dictionary to the dialog list
        self.dialog.append(neue_frage)
        # Perform an OpenAI API call and retrieve the response
        ergebnis = openai.Completion.create(
            engine="gpt-3.5-turbo",
            prompt=self.dialog,
            max_tokens=1024,
            n=1,
            stop=None,
            temperature=0.5,
        )
        # Extract the response from the API response
        antwort = ergebnis.choices[0].text
        # Create a new dictionary with the role "assistant" and the content of the answer
        neue_antwort = {"role":"assistant","content":antwort}
        # Add the new dictionary to the dialog list
        self.dialog.append(neue_antwort)
        # Update the dialog list to use the last two added dictionaries as input for the next request
        self.dialog[-1]["prompt"] = True
        # Return the answer and updated dialog list
        return antwort, self.dialog

# Load the API key from a file
with open('api.key', 'r') as api_key:
    API_KEY=api_key.read()

# Create a ChatGPT instance
chat_gpt=ChatGPT(API_KEY,"be a code terminal")

# Loop to receive questions from the user and receive responses from ChatGPT
while (frage := input('\n> ')) != 'X':
    antwort, dialog=chat_gpt.fragen(frage)
    # Print the response
    print(antwort)
    # Print the dialog list
    print(dialog[-2:])   # Output the last two elements (user question and assistant response) of the dialog list
    enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you send a [history of conversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/openai/how-to/chatgpt?pivots=programming-language-chat-completions#creating-a-basic-conversation-loop)

Try to add a [user field](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create#chat/create-user) in `openai.Completion.create` and change the `openai.Completion.create` to `openai.ChatCompletion.create`